# AttributeError (Learn Python the Hard Way)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I just want to find out why this piece of code is returning errors. I'm getting two AttributeErrors and don't know why.

Error 1.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex39a.py", line 47, in <module>
    for console, abbrev in consoles.items():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Error 2.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex39a.py", line 55, in <module>
    console = consoles.get('SEGA Dreamcast', None)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Its modified from exercise 39 in the 'Learn Python the Hard Way' is anyone is familiar with it.

I've marked just above which sections of code are returning errors with a #error.

```
consoles = {
    'Nintendo Entertainment System': 'NES',
    'SEGA Saturn': 'Saturn',
    'Playstation 3': 'PS3',
    'Xbox 360': '360',
    'Atari 2600': '2600'
}

games = {
    'NES': 'Castlevania',
    'Saturn': 'SEGA Rally Championship',
    'PS3': 'Assassins Creed 2'
}
games['360'] = 'Halo 3'
games['2600'] = 'Space Invaders'

print '-' * 10
print "The 360 has: ", games['360']
print "The 2600 has: ", games ['2600']

print '-' * 10
print "The Atari 2600s abbreviation is: ", consoles['Atari 2600']
print "The Nintendo Entertainment Systems abbreviation is: ", consoles['Nintendo Entertainment System']

print '-' * 10
print "The Atari 2600 has: ", games[consoles['Atari 2600']]
print "The Playstation 3 has: ", games[consoles['Playstation 3']]

print '-' * 10
for consoles, abbrev in consoles.items():
    print "%s is abbreviated %s" % (consoles, abbrev)

print '-' * 10
for abbrev, games in games.items():
    print "%s has the game %s" % (abbrev, games)
#error  
print '-' * 10
for console, abbrev in consoles.items():
    print "%s console is abbreviated %s and has the game %s" % (
        console, abbrev, games[abbrev])
#error          
print '-' * 10
#safely get an abbreviation for a console that might not be there
console = consoles.get('SEGA Dreamcast', None)

if not console:
    print "Sorry, that console is too shit to list."


game = games.get('Resident Evil: Code Veronica', 'Does Not Exist')
print "That game is for the: %s" % game
```

Comment: You overwrote the value of `consoles` in `for consoles, abbrev in consoles.items()`.

Comment: Same for, `games` in line 36, `for abbrev, games`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use the same iterator name while looping through `consoles` dictionary and `games` dictionary. That way, `consoles` as well as `games` dictionaries are being converted to some other string. Try this :

```
consoles = {
    'Nintendo Entertainment System': 'NES',
    'SEGA Saturn': 'Saturn',
    'Playstation 3': 'PS3',
    'Xbox 360': '360',
    'Atari 2600': '2600'
}

games = {
    'NES': 'Castlevania',
    'Saturn': 'SEGA Rally Championship',
    'PS3': 'Assassins Creed 2'
}
games['360'] = 'Halo 3'
games['2600'] = 'Space Invaders'

print '-' * 10
print "The 360 has: ", games['360']
print "The 2600 has: ", games ['2600']

print '-' * 10
print "The Atari 2600s abbreviation is: ", consoles['Atari 2600']
print "The Nintendo Entertainment Systems abbreviation is: ", consoles['Nintendo Entertainment System']

print '-' * 10
print "The Atari 2600 has: ", games[consoles['Atari 2600']]
print "The Playstation 3 has: ", games[consoles['Playstation 3']]

print '-' * 10
# CHANGE HERE
for console, abbrev in consoles.items():
    print "%s is abbreviated %s" % (console, abbrev)

print '-' * 10
# CHANGE HERE
for abbrev, game in games.items():
    print "%s has the game %s" % (abbrev, game)
print '-' * 10
for console, abbrev in consoles.items():
    print "%s console is abbreviated %s and has the game %s" % (
        console, abbrev, games[abbrev])
print '-' * 10
#safely get an abbreviation for a console that might not be there
console = consoles.get('SEGA Dreamcast', None)

if not console:
    print "Sorry, that console is too shit to list."


game = games.get('Resident Evil: Code Veronica', 'Does Not Exist')
print "That game is for the: %s" % game
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed every use of 'console' to 'hardware' and 'game' to 'software' to eliminate the confusion.